# What is the gcc alternate of "relro" and "now" flags in "mingw-gcc"?

Tags: gcc, mingw

What is the gcc alternate of  gcc flag "relro"  in "mingw-gcc" ?

Answer (score 1):

MinGW is actually GCC, so the flags are the same. But some flags depend on platform-specifics.

Relocation Read-Only (RELRO) is specifically for ELF binaries, which are not supported on Windows.

Instead Windows uses the PE/PE+ format (which is based on the COFF format).

There is support for `-Wl,--dynamicbase` and ASLR (address space layout randomization) that you could take a look at to see if it helps you accomplish your goal.